Why is older JDK8 not accepting certificates signed by our own CA?
We're trying to secure a connection from a Java-program to a remote server. The server is presenting a certificate signed by our own CA, and our Java-program is rejecting that:
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)

The error only happens with older JDK8 patch-levels, however: 8u111. With 8u401 everything works...
The $JAVAHOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts is a symlink to the same file for both older and newer JDK-versions, and that file does contain our CAs' certificates, according to keytool -list:
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 57:4D:F6:93:1E:27:80:39:66:7B.....
OURCOMPANY
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 83:81:CF:C1:68:99:29:F0:D2:C1.....
OURCOMPANY

Is there anything else, something about the certificates themselves, that makes them unusable with the older JDK? Is it the digest-method (SHA-256), that the older JDK does not recognize -- I see, that the cacerts file, that came with the older version originally, used 1024-bit RSA for fingerprinting...
Is there a means to somehow enable the usage of SHA-256 without upgrading the entire JDK (which we cannot do at the moment for unrelated reasons)?
Can we, for example, import our CAs' certificates into the older KeyStore -- using the RSA 1024 fingerprinting, or is the digest-method determined by the certificate itself?

The exception message doesn't say it does not accept the certificate, but that the program has problems with the handshake. Maybe the old Java version doesn't support an algorithm that is available in the newer version? (Or the algorithm is not enabled there, or the keylength is not supported - did you check that the "export restrictions" have the same setting on both JVMs?) The available algorithms for handshakes are offered by the server and not related to the certificates.

We're an American company and the older JDK was obtained straight from Oracle back then... But how would I compare the export restrictions?

The fingerprint is computed ONLY for display to the user; it is not in the certificate and has no effect at all on use of the certificate for TLS. And fingerprint never uses, and never has used, "1024-bit RSA" or any other RSA. @cyberbrain+ for 1.2 down (which is all 8u111 supports) the ciphersuite does include keyexchange which is affected by certificate&key -- e.g. ECDHE-RSA-symalg suites only work with RSA cert&key, ECDHE-ECDSA-symalg suites only work with EC(DSA) cert&key. But this is the same for 111 and 401, while the symmetric part differs due to 'policy' as you say.

You probably need to download and activate the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files from Oracle.
Effectively you can turn on and off the stronger encryption in Java with them. (You will need an Oracle Account for the download.)
The linked page says

The unlimited policy files are required only for JDK 8, 7, and 6 updates earlier than 8u161, 7u171, and 6u181. On those versions and later, the stronger cryptographic algorithms are available by default.

This would fit with your observation that 8u111 does not perform the handshake while 8u401 does.

Yep! That was it...

Another less likely difference is that 8 below 8u261 only supports protocols up to TLSv1.2; 8u261 up supports TLSv1.3 as well. But I'd be surprised to find today a server that requires 1.3. In 5 years maybe, but not today.
